# Understanding convergence in $L^P$ ( Through a counter example )

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $1<p_0<\infty$. I am looking to find an example of a sequence $\{f_k\}_{k\in \mathbb N}$ such that ${f_k}\in L^P$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$ , $ f_k\xrightarrow {}0$ in $L^P$ , for $1<p<p_0$ , but $f_k$ does not converge in $L^{p_0}$

Comment: $u_k(x) = k^{1/2} 1_{x \in [0,1/k]}$ converges (to $0$) in $L^p$ iff $p < 2$

Comment: In the opposite direction, take $v_k(x) = k^{-1/2} 1_{x \in [0,k]}$ which converges (to $0$) in $L^p$ iff $p > 2$

Comment: @user1952009 Put your comment as an answer with a little bit more explanation and I will mark it as a correct answer to close the question !